# How to upload and save an image to /assets/images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Total noob question here, but how would I make a simple upload portal that allows me to upload an image to the /assets/images folder?  It doesn't need to be saved to an object at all.  I just need to upload an image.

I have active admin, if that is of any assistance.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written any code? What libraries, of any, are you using? What's not working? Are uploaded files intended to be publicly accessible? (In which case, you could place them in `./public`.) Is there a good reason for you to store them locally on the server? This is a valid approach, but uncommon; it would be more normal to store them in the database or perhaps on some cloud storage - e.g. S3.

Comment: Carrierwave is a great gem to use as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

So as not to further increase the size of the project folder I recommend storing images in a database.

This gem will help you achieve image uploads - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 0):

Rails provide many gems for uploading like :

Paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

CarrierWave : https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

---

Answer (score 0):

The `assets/images` folder in rails is intended for assets that your project uses, such as the company/site/project logo, icons, favicons, etcetera. It isn't meant to be a folder for uploading user nor admin  generated assets.

If it is an image that needs to be user administered, then you should use a server for that such as Amazon S3.

[Here is a nice Heroku tutorial on that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveAdmin visit the [wiki page](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki) for links to various tutorials and how-tos, including [this one for PaperClip](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/23/file-upload-active-admin-paperclip/)